# Configure Sharepoint Server site to send email attachments

Tags: attachments

We want to use Sharepoint to send attachments to secure users email group.    Basically sending attachment once if verified metadata that will indicate which email user group needs to receive the attachment.

Can Sharepoint send email attachments to user groups?

Thanks,
Ann

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this in code (C#/VB)?

If so, I don't think you can send an email to a SharePoint Group, but you will be able to enumerate that group, get all the users' email address from it, and send an email to each in turn.

If you're doing this with a workflow, I'm not entirely certain - only way is to try and see what happens (create a SharePoint Designer workflow to test if you like, very simple test to a SharePoint Group that you create as a test with 2 users in it, for example, and create a task in the workflow that sends an email to that workflow).

As for sending attachments - not sure if SharePoint can do this out of the box, the idea being that attachments are a thing of the past and that documents, etc. are linked to in the email that's sent.

Comment: SharePoint Designer does not allow attachments to be sent as part of a workflow, but if you are lucky enough to have Nintex Workflow in your organisation then it is possible. Aternatively there are 3rd party approaches, see http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/send-rich-emails-with-attachments-from.html (Shameless self promoting plug :-)

Answer (score 0):

The plan was to use Sharepoint to check permissions for documents and send out the file that was sent into Sharepoint and email to a list of people that have the proper permissions.   We were hoping that is was part of the functionality already.   Seems like we might have to change the plan and/or investigate support of mobile applications.

Comment: Ann - you've put this comment in as an ANSWER to your question. It would be better to edit your orig question and put this there. Please read FAQ top right about how this site works.